# Delete Folder from Right Click Menu in Listview (Windows Forms, C#, Net)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net

I have been unable to find a good example of making a rightclick menu from a listview in winforms.

I am scaning a hardrive for folders, and I want to make a right click menu. I can drag a context menu strip into my listview that shows the folders in a detail: foldername and size.
And when I rightclick, I can see my menu.

How can I add a function that will delete the selected directory and its content? Also, how can I delete it from the listview?

I have found code that deletes the text from listview but no good examples on actually deleting contents behind what is showing!

Any code is highly appreciated!

Comment: Because "deleting the contents behind what's showing" is very specific to your application.

Comment: a directory with files, it might be a music album, or a picture album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you building the data in the list view?  You could just store the path in the tag of the listview item.  Since you know how to get at the item in the list view to delete it, you can simply access its tag property before you delete it and run a System.IO.Directory.Delete method.